# How to get flattened list of all inner level nested keys in dictionary - python?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I'm trying to get a list of all keys in the nested level of my dictionary.

My dictionary resembles:

```
my_dict= {
 'DICT':{
  'level_1a':{
   'level_2a':{}
  },
  'level_1b': {
   'level_2b':{},
   'level_2c':{}
  }
}
```

My desired output should resemble:

```
['level_2a', 'level_2b', 'level_2c']
```

What I've tried:

```
[list(v) for k, v in json['DICT'].items()]
```

My current output:

```
[['level_2a'], ['level_2b', 'level_2c']]
```

I want my result to be fully flattened to a single-level list. I've tried flattening libraries but the result tends to appear as: `['level_2a', 'level_2blevel_2c']` which is incorrect. Not looking to make the code more complex by creating another method just to flatten this list.

Would appreciate some help, thank you!

Comment: Your desired output is `['level_2a', 'level_2b', 'level_2c']` I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
my_dict = {
    "DICT": {
        "level_1a": {"level_2a": {}},
        "level_1b": {"level_2b": {}, "level_2c": {}},
    }
}
lst = [vv for v in my_dict["DICT"].values() for vv in v]
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```py
['level_2a', 'level_2b', 'level_2c']
```

Comment: As a follow-up, if I have a level 1 list with `['level_1b']` (for example), how can I get only the level 2 values only corresponding to the values in the level 1 list?

(Totally cool if you can't answer this and I need to make another post)

Comment: @RicardoFrancois To not clutter comment section I'd suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow. I'll try to look at it.

Comment: Sounds good. Here's my question, if you have time to look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68332161/how-to-get-list-of-all-inner-level-nested-keys-in-python-dictionary-correspondin