# How to get list of all inner level nested keys in python dictionary corresponding to values in a different list?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

Suppose I have a list similar to `my_list = ['level_1b']`. My dictionary resembles:

```
my_dict= {
 'DICT':{
  'level_1a':{
   'level_2a':{}
  },
  'level_1b': {
   'level_2b':{},
   'level_2c':{}
  }
}
```

The current code I have extracts all the inner level nested keys within this dictionary:

`[key for level in my_dict["DICT"].values() for key in level]` with output as `['level_2a', 'level_2b', 'level_2c']`.

How would I go about filtering this list into only extracting the level 2 values corresponding to the level 1 values that I include in `my_list`? I'm thinking another `for` loop but can't wrap my head around how this would be executed.

I've also tried:
`[list(my_dict['DICT'][level]) for level in levels]` but the output isn't exactly correct.

Given `my_list` and `my_dict`, my ideal output for this minimum reproducible example should be: `['level_2b', 'level_2c']`.

Of course, the code is to be functional with more than 1 items in `my_list` as well. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it:

```
  [(nested_key) for key, value in my_dict["DICT"].items() for nested_key in value.keys() if key in my_list]
```

Output:

```
['level_2b', 'level_2c']
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Just curious - why is `(nested_key)` wrapped with parentheses?

Answer (score 2):

This should work. Just not a list comprehension anymore, thus easier to think about.

```py
level2_keys = []
for level1_key in my_list:
    level2_keys.extend(my_dict["DICT"][level1_key].keys())
```